How to fix arms clipping into body problem
I'm working on a character model in Blender and I'm encountering an issue where the character's arms are clipping into the body. I've attached an images to illustrate the problem. How it can be fixed?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/12dUxCo_Pzm5ebySavQfggQdNbAJe88xS/view?usp=sharing

Hello could you please highlight the part you are talking about? You may need to correct with some trick, like shapekeys for example

https://imgur.com/a/0nqw0fe

You could create a new shapekey then select some vertices in Edit mode:

Activate the Proportional Editing option, move these vertices until you are glad with the result:

Keyframe the shapekey at 1 when the arm is bent, or create a driver that will automatize the process:


Can you send blend file please

Also it stretches the mesh

It needs to be precisely worked, I'm not sure that there's any magic solution, another one would be to create bones that wouls control this vertices but I doubt it would be easier
